# Get public asset file after deploy

Tags: java, playframework

In localhost, everything works well.

I am getting files from assets in a following way:

```
File[] pluginFiles = Play.getFile("\\target\\scala-2.10\\classes\\public\\plugins").listFiles()
```

But when I deploy application, I lose target folder and cannot access it in this way anymore.

Is there way of accessing files relative to deployment .jar or similar?

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```
File[] files = play.api.Play.getFile("public/plugins", play.Play.application().getWrappedApplication()).listFiles();
```

Or try this:

```
File[] files = play.Play.application().getFile("public/plugins").listFiles();
```

Comment: too many arguments for method getFile: (relativePath: String)(implicit app: play.api.Application)java.io.File

Comment: I edited the answer. Make sure you use `play.api.Play` class rather than `play.Play`.

Comment: Unfortunately no. First example does not compile, and second compiles but it returns null in localhost. I do not think I would benefit from deploying app with second line.

Comment: Of course :) Yes, I already noticed that it was "public/js" in example prior to editing.